# Writing a view to allow user to add related data for a customer, like comments for example; on a single page

Tags: python, django, view, model

I have working models, forms, views and urls for a django CRUD app managing customer functions for a business. I just cant seem to figure out how to write a view to allow a user to add comments, or other data related to the customer and stored in other models using a single view and template.

So for example; for customer a, all the comments for customer a with the option to add, amend etc.. and the same for the other related models.

I understand how to do it for one I will be able to make quick progress. (old school programmer here)

Here is what I am working with - keeping it simple.

MODELS

```
class Emergency(models.Model):

    # Fields
    name = CharField(null = False, blank = False, max_length=60)
    address = TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='Street and town', verbose_name='Address')
    telephone = CharField(blank=False, null=False, unique= True, max_length=20)
    relationship = CharField(choices=(('P',  'Parent'),('S',  'Son'),('D',  'Daughter'),('R',  'Relative'),('L',  'Partner')),max_length = 1,default='R')


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pk',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.pk

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse('conform_emergency_detail', args=(self.pk,))

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('conform_emergency_update', args=(self.pk,))


class Client(models.Model):

    # Fields
    surname = CharField(null = False, blank = False, max_length=30)
    name = CharField(null = False, blank = False, max_length=60)

    # Relationship Fields
    emergencycontact = models.ForeignKey(Emergency, on_delete=models.CASCADE, name = 'Emergency Contact')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pk',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.pk

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('conform_client_detail', args=(self.pk,))

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('conform_client_update', args=(self.pk,))


class Clientnotes(models.Model):

    # Fields
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', blank=True)
    created = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    last_updated = DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    note = CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length= 300 )

    # Relationship Fields
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='clientnotes_modified_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE, name= 'Changed by')
    clientnotes = models.ManyToManyField(Client, name = 'Clients notes')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.slug

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('conform_clientnotes_detail', args=(self.slug,))

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('conform_clientnotes_update', args=(self.slug,))
```

FORMS

```
class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ['surname', 'name']

class ClientnotesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Clientnotes
        readonly_fields = ['slug', 'modified_by']
        fields = ['note']
```

VIEWS

```
class ClientListView(ListView):
    model = Client


class ClientCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Client
    form_class = ClientForm


class ClientDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Client


class ClientUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Client
    form_class = ClientForm
```

TEMPLATE NAMES

```
client_detail.html
client_form.html
client_list.html
```

I have simple views, forms and templates to list, view detail and add and it all works well - with the exception of related models because i am not able to add both models at the same time. I need a simple clear simpletons guide with what i have provided so it clicks into place.

Comment: Welcome to SO Cameron Duodu! Could you be a little more specific as to what your question is?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I guess my django is weak.  I need a view that will allow me to add data, for client, such as client comments and emergency contact - for a given client.  It could be that i am still thinking in the old school way, but i dont seem to grasp how to get that done on a single view.  Are you able to help?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about Django, so I'm not much help. The information you have provided will help others though!

Comment: I think you want something that uses a foreign key of the User model? So that details related to that user is only shown. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.  I want to show, update only comments etc.. for a particular user only.